# Continue pagenumbering after appendices with the value before the appendices

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I'm writing my thesis and I encounter the following problem. I want the pagenumber to start at 1 in my appendix and after the appendix, it should continue with the original page numbering in my mainmatter. 
For example: 1, 2, 3, App. -1-, App. -2-, App. -3-, 4, 5, 6 ... I can't manage to do it.
Below is a MWE with some text in it.

The template from school has a structure in the form of

```
\mainmatter
% Here do the chapters come
\appendix
%a appendix text
\backmatter
% bibliography
```

I want my pagenumbering change only for the appendix. 
I defined my own custom page number style right after `\appendix` as follows:

```
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{App. - \arabic{page} -}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
Here is text.
This is normal arabic page numbering.
\newpage
Some more text
\newpage

\appendixpage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{App. - \arabic{page} -}

\chapter{First appendix}
\newpage

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}% this line make the arabic page number reset to one , but it    should continue where the pagenumber before the appendix stopped. 
Here comes the bibliography. I want this page numbering to be arabic and have a value that is the arabic value when there where no appendices. This page should have page number `4'

so 1, 2, 3 App. -1-, App. -2-, App. -3-, 4 , 5...

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!
Lennert

Comment: Why is there an `\appendixpage` command and `\appendix` does not use chapters normally, rather `\section` ...

Comment: May I suggest that use roman numbering for the appendix pages or something, it might be a little confusing, when page numbers restart due to the appendix and then continue after it?

Comment: The template uses a custom made documentclass from our university. This was based on the memoir-class, all I know is that we should do it this way. Thanks for your answer here below, I accepted it because it did the trick. I will have a look at your improved answer when I have some more time. Thanks and greetings from Belgium!

Comment: About the numbering style: I used the arabic style because it gave me the nicest looks in the TOC. I thought about it but I choose the arabic style ;)

Comment: Well, happy `texing` anyway. I readily answer questions. The `\appendixpage` is a little weird, in my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dummy page counter to save the page number and restore it back after beginning of the `\backmatter` content.

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\newcounter{originalpagenumber}%
\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
Here is text.
This is normal arabic page numbering.
\newpage
Some more text
\newpage


\setcounter{originalpagenumber}{\number\value{page}}%
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\appendixpage
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{App. - \arabic{page} -}

\chapter{First appendix}
\newpage
\chapter{Second Appendix}%

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}% 
\setcounter{page}{\number\value{originalpagenumber}}
%this line make the arabic page number reset to one , but it    should continue where the pagenumber before the appendix stopped. 
Here comes the bibliography. I want this page numbering to be arabic and have a value that is the arabic value when there where no appendices. This page should have page number `4'

so 1, 2, 3 App. -1-, App. -2-, App. -3-, 4 , 5...

\end{document}
```

**Improved version, with automatic switching of page numbers**

```
\documentclass{memoir}%

\newcounter{PageNumberBeforeAppendix}%

\let\LaTeXStandardThePage\thepage
\let\LaTeXStandardAppendix\appendix%
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{PageNumberBeforeAppendix}{\number\value{page}}%
\setcounter{page}{1}%
\LaTeXStandardAppendix%
}%

\let\LaTeXStandardBackmatter\backmatter
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{%
\cleardoublepage%
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\LaTeXStandardThePage}%
\setcounter{page}{\number\value{PageNumberBeforeAppendix}}
\LaTeXStandardBackmatter%
}%


\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
Here is text.
This is normal arabic page numbering.
\newpage
Some more text
\newpage


\renewcommand*{\thepage}{App. - \arabic{page} -}
%\appendixpage 
\appendix

\chapter{First appendix}


\backmatter
%this line make the arabic page number reset to one , but it    should continue where the pagenumber before the appendix stopped. 
Here comes the bibliography. I want this page numbering to be arabic and have a value that is the arabic value when there where no appendices. This page should have page number `4'

so 1, 2, 3 App. -1-, App. -2-, App. -3-, 4 , 5...

\end{document}
```